# How to control the order of models in the modelstructure panel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to improve the loading speed when loading multiple models. I can do so by using Promise.all which loads the models in parallel instead of in series. The problem however is that as you have no control over which model is loaded first that you also don't have control over the order of the models in the modulestructure panel.

Is there any way to control the order of models in the modelstructurepanel once the models are loaded? Could you perhaps move them up/down afterwards? Or even better, can you hook into some event just before adding it to the modelstructure where you can specify on what position it will be inserted?

The code below is not my real implementation, but is a modification of Michael Beale's example from https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7 and shows the principle of my goal here.

```
var viewer;

loadModels([
    { urn: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dnJwYXJ0eTIvcnN0X2Jhc2ljX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0LnJ2dA", xform: { x: -60, y: 0, z: 0 } },
    { urn: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dnJwYXJ0eTIvNDMyJTIwTmFwYS5ydnQ", xform: { x: 60, y: 0, z: 0 } },
    { urn: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dnJwYXJ0eTEvcmFjLnJ2dA", xform: { x: 50, y: 0, z: -50 } },
    { urn: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dnJwYXJ0eTEvcmFjLnJ2dA", xform: { x: -50, y: 0, z: -50 } }
]);

function loadModels(urns) {
    const viewerOptions = {
        env: "AutodeskProduction",
        accessToken: _adsk.token.access_token,
        extensions: []
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(viewerOptions, async() => {
        const div = document.getElementById("forgeViewer");
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(div);
        viewer.start();
        await Promise.all(urns.map(loadDocument));

        // Order of models in viewer.modelstructure is now depending on download speed of each model and not following the order in urns array
    });

    async function loadDocument(m) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${m.urn}`, (doc)=>{
                loadDocumentNode(doc).then(m =>{
                    resolve();
                })
            });
        });
    }

    async function loadDocumentNode(doc) {
        var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        return await viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, {
            preserveView: true,
            keepCurrentModels: true,
            keepCurrentModels: true,
            globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to load the first model, then wait the GEOMETRY_LOADED event, then load the rest of the models in parallel.

```
view = new SheetsView(viewer);
view.load(urn, sheets, viewState);


class SheetsView {

constructor(viewer) {
    this.viewer = viewer;
    this.sheets = [];  //Model objects for each 2D sheet
    this.model3d = null; // model object for root 3D node
    this.bub3D = null; // viewable for 3D model
    this.options = {keepCurrentModels: true};
}

// loads 3D base model and select 2D sheets
// URN:         urn of primary 3D model
// sheets:     array of sheets { id: index of 2d sheet, x,y,z, scale,  vert }
// viewState:  initial camera view state.  viewState = viewer.getState({viewport: true, objectSet: true});

async load(urn, sheets, viewState) {

    this.sheets = sheets;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load( urn, async doc => {
        this.bub3D = doc.getRoot().search({type:'geometry', role: "3d" })[0];
        let bub2Ds = doc.getRoot().search({type:'geometry', role: "2d" });
        doc.downloadAecModelData();
        // first, load 3D model, then wait for GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT
        this.model3d = await this._loadmodel(doc, this.bub3D, this.options);

        // second, load 2D (or3D) models in parallel
        for (let sheet of sheets) {
            sheet.model = (await this._loadmodel(doc, bub2Ds[sheet.id], this.options )).model;
        };                
        this._finishLoad(viewState);
    })        
}


async _loadmodel(doc, viewable, options) {

    let viewer = this.viewer;
    return await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, options).then( model => {
            viewable.model = model;
            viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, e => { 
                resolve(e);
            }, {once : true}); 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but I'm not sure if you understood my problem. I only have one viewable per document, not multiple. I also see now that my code example was missing some crucial parts about Promise.all. I'm loading the documents in parallel with Promise.all that causes a kind of random order of models in the modelstructure panel. I've updated my code example on this. My goal here is to control the order of the models in the modelstructure panel. I don't see how your code example controls that. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi Joep,  It controls the sequence, by resolving the promise once the model's 'GEOMETRY_LOADED' event has triggered.  I also use a 'once:true' to avoid duplicate triggers - that's important.
Loading geometry event, loads important startup files, to get the viewer to operate.  These must be in sequence.  After that, the mesh files, etc, can load concurrently.  If you want to force everything to be sequential, you can use a TEXTURE_LOADED event, which will wait until all files have loaded, before moving onto the next model.

Comment: my example code demonstrates multi-model loading in sequence for one viewable with 4 sheets, via an array.  However, the code is generic, and you can specify multiple URNs instead, by changing the array and the interface.

Comment: I see how it controls the sequence indeed, but not how this improves loading speed while maintaining control over the order of models in the modelstructure pael. What I managed to do sofar is to load all documents with Promise.all. That already improves performance quite a lot. But loading the documentNode still needs te be run in sequence or otherwise the order of models in the modeltructure panel is random.

Comment: It doesn’t really improve loading speed if that’s what you were after.  You would want to use partial loading for that.  Tandem Views And Tandem API is a more advanced example of multi mode loading with partial loads using forge viewer.  It shows what is possible.